# Find the missing bee in the picture

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Lots of ladybugs attacking the city! However, we are looking for a missing bee. Can you find it?

[image]

Comment: Please someone add proper tags.

Comment: why negative vote?

Comment: Don't worry about mean-spirited downvoters. Keep up the good work.

Comment: Very nice visuals. Did you draw it yourself or find it somewhere? If the first: Well done! If the second, it would be good to give reference.

Comment: thanks :-), I found the picture in [this website](http://tse1.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.M765e5c45979e2cee10d54a2bfdb7024co0). I paint it myself with "Gimp" and used "Tux paint" for ladybugs. Unfortunately, I didn't have much time for higher quality work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right here:

> [image]

which is clearly

> Braille

Answer (score 7):

Not really sure, but

> These windows:
> [image]
> suggests that the word "BEE" is hidden in there (since the two last windows are identical). When ignoring the middle row of each window and treating the 2x2 grid as [Braille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille), you get `BEE`.

Comment: Got you by 8 seconds (A)

Comment: @Will I shouldn't have double-checked the result...

Comment: I'm laughing to myself because the fact we answered within 10 seconds doesn't exactly refute us being the same person...

Comment: @Will I recently answered the same *second* as other answerer